# nghttp2_session.c:2178: session_prep_frame: Assertion `session->last_sent_stream_id < frame->hd.stream_id' failed？

Tags: c++, http, libcurl

I am using `libcurl 8.2.1` from yum repo `cityfan`.

It ran on aws for a long time, Recently i restart aws.

And the long-time-good-run c++ process errored with

```
nghttp2_session.c:2178: session_prep_frame: Assertion `session->last_sent_stream_id < frame->hd.stream_id' failed.
```

Could you help on this? I googled, found nothing, maybe it's a new feature?

Comment: Did you check if the `nghttp2` library version is compatible with `libcurl` 8.2.1? and if any recent updates might have introduced breaking changes...